# how would you format this to string

Tags: java

I have this

```
public String toString()
{
    String s = "";
    for (int r = 0; r != 7 ; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c != 7 ; c++) 
        {
            s += String.format("%02d " ,board[r][c]);
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

and I need it to return like this

01  04  39  20  53  06  37  22
40  19  02  05  38  21  52  07
03  46  61  00  57  54  23  36
18  41  56  49  60  00  08  51
47  14  45  58  55  50  35  24
42  17  48  27  00  59  32  09
13  28  15  44  11  30  25  34
16  43  12  29  26  33  10  31

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Can you explain what you've tried so far?

Comment: yeah i tried adding \n but it would skip after everyone

Comment: I can give you a hint: you need a line break after each row of the board.

Comment: You probably need something like `s += System.lineSeparator();` after the inner loop...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your adding a space ever line but never a new line char

```
public String toString()
{
    String s = "";
    for (int r = 0; r != 7 ; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c != 7 ; c++) 
        {
           s += String.format("%02d " ,board[r][c]);
        }
        s += String.format("%n");
    }
        return s;
}
```

%n is the platform independent new line char

Comment: I'm wrong, %n is plataform INDEPENDENT new line char?! so if running on linux with '\n' this would be independent and is the correct new line for Windows? It should not be plataform DEPENDENT or just plataform new line char!? _http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax_ **'n'  line separator  The result is the platform-specific line separator**

Comment: Sorry i could have phrased that better, Its obtains the platform new line. So its platform independent code

Answer (score 1):

Little tip: use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). Repeatedly appending to `String`s in loops makes every decent programmer cringe.

```
private static final String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");

public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

    for (int r = 0; r != 7 ; r++)
    {
         for (int c = 0; c != 7 ; c++) 
         {
               s.append( String.format("%02d ", board[r][c] );
         }

         // On each outer-loop iteration, add a platform 
         // independent line separator (e.g. on Linux, it's "\n")
         s.append( NEW_LINE );
    }

    return s.toString();
}
```

**Edit**: On @Diego C Nascimento's suggestion, the new line separator should be a class constant.

Comment: Just a hint: it would be more interesting to get the line separator at the start of the method on a variable and then just use it avoiding the call to System.getProperty("line.separator")

Comment: why not use `System.lineSeparator()`?

Comment: @randomstring Works either way. Interesting enough, with `getProperty` you could hack the system line separator, to return something else. But that's just silly and offtopic.